# Is adding users to the group www-data safe on Debian?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, security, www-data

Many PHP applications do self-configuration and self-updating. This requires **apache** to have write access to the PHP files. While `chgrp`'ing them all to **www-data** appears like a good practice to avoid making them world writable, I also wish to allow users to create new files and edit existing one.

Is adding users to the group **www-data** safe on Debian? For example:

```
775 root www-data /var/www
644 john www-data /var/www/johns_php_application.php
660 john www-data /var/www/johns_php_applications_configuration_file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually create a group called "webdev" and add my web developer user and www-data to the group and give it the appropriate permissions for the site/directory/files, etc.

Comment: Good idea, i did not think of going the other way around. Adding the httpd to the developer's group is more logical then the developers in the httpd's group. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use `mod_userdir`?

Comment: mod_userdir dont setuid or setgid apache to the user. Files are still not writable unless they are chmod'ed 777.